# Native way to send custom object in JMS queue? (citrus-simulator)

Tags: testing, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'm looking for a native (correct, in terms of the framework) way to send thirdparty (custom) Object to JMS in **citrus-simulator**? 
I have tried:

```
scenario
.send()
.payloadModel(myObject);
```

but in JMS queue myObject appears as *com.consol.citrus.message.DefaultMessage* instead of *com...myObject*.

**Example:**
Scenario - receives http POST request (as trigger) and send's JMS Object to message queue.

**config**

```
...
.useObjectMessages(true)
...
```

**scenario**

```
  ...
    import com.temafon.data.MORequest;

    @Scenario("morequest")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/simulator/morequest",method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public class JmsMoRequestScenario extends AbstractSimulatorScenario {

    @Override
    public void run(ScenarioDesigner scenario) {
       MORequest request = new MORequest(12345678901L, "USSD", "1172", "ON", 
       11L);
            request.setSourcePort(3);

        scenario
                .receive()
                .payload("getmorequest");

        scenario
                .send("jms.queue.destination")
                .payloadModel(request);
```

After this case, I expect to get in jms.queue.destination something like screen 1

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLxY3.png)

[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INk5v.png)

P.S. I have implemented workaround already, with *JavaActionBuilder* and *jmsTemplate.send* in additional class and

```
scenario
.java(//Object).method(//instance");
```

But it doesn't seems like correct citrus-simulator way

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `payloadModel()` in Citrus Java DSL will always result in some kind of marshalled representation of the object and this is not what you want. Neither is using `.useObjectMessages(true)` working for you because this results in the whole Citrus message object to be used as message payload.

You need to define a complete Citrus message object and that will remain untouched in terms of payload creation for the JMS destination. Citrus is then automatically using a JMS object message with proper object payload.

```
MORequest request = new MORequest(12345678901L, "USSD", "1172", "ON", 11L);
request.setSourcePort(3);

scenario
    .receive()
    .payload("getmorequest");

scenario
    .send("jms.queue.destination")
    .message(new JmsMessage(request));
```

Note that I am using the `.message()` fluent API instead of the `payloadModel()` API. The message API receives a Citrus message object such as `com.consol.citrus.jms.message.JmsMessage` or `com.consol.citrus.message.DefaultMessage`

Your custom domain model object `request` is used as constructor arg and will result in the JMS message as object payload as is. Of course `MORequest` must be of type `java.io.Serializable`